# Call PowerCLI script from PHP

Tags: php, powershell, powercli

I want to build a small webinterface to grant our users certain permissions for handling linked clones. 
On the webserver (Windows Datacenter 2008 R2 running IIS), I have installed PowerCLI. The website runs under my user-account (domain admin), to rule out any permission issues.

My PHP file looks like this:

```
$PowerCliCommand="C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -PSConsoleFile \"C:\\Progra~2\\VMware\\Infrastructure\\vSphere PowerCLI\\vim.psc1\" -file C:\inetpub\lcmgmt\listlcs.ps1";
echo $PowerCliCommand . "<br>";
exec($PowerCliCommand, $Output, $ErrorReturned);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($Output);

print_r($ErrorReturned);
echo "</pre>";
```

I call the consolefile from `\progra~2`, as `\program files (x86)` kept bugging me with issues.

The output of PHP in my browser is as follows:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -PSConsoleFile C:\Progra~2\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\vim.psc1" -file C:\inetpub\lcmgmt\listlcs.ps1
Array 
(   
    [0] => Connect-VIserver : The term 'Connect-VIserver' is not recognized as
> the name of
    [1] =>  a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of th
    [2] => e name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try agai
    [3] => n.
    [4] => At C:\inetpub\lcmgmt\listlcs.ps1:4 char:2
    [5] => +  Connect-VIserver -server "MyVSserver"
```

The PowerShell script called looks like this:

```
Connect-VIserver -server "MyVSserver"
$VDICluster=get-cluster -Name "MyCluster"
get-vm -location  $VDICluster -name "Server*"
```

When calling the full command (the first line in my PHP output) from a command prompt on the webserver, running on my account (the same account used in IIS), everything works fine, I get the information on my linked clones. 
As you can see the browser output reports that the PowerCLI commands are unknown. 
I'm completely lost, anybody has experience on this?

Comment: "the same account used in IIS"? You mean you operate that deamon under a normal user account?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Yes, I run (purely as a test, I'll create a dedicated service account once his works) the IIS website under my personal domain admin account to rule out any permission restrictions. 
I don't see how the path can be in the way here, I specify the full path to all files called.

Comment: Well, `Connect-VIserver` certainly is _not_ an absolute path...

Comment: What is your execution policy set to? It might be that PowerShell is telling you that it's not able to load the PowerCLI script as the execution policy prevents it and PHP isn't picking up `STDERR`. You could try to append `2>&1` to the end of your command.

Comment: You might have a look at [WebCommander](https://labs.vmware.com/flings/webcommander)

Comment: Hi Seth, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately adding 2>&1 to the end of the command doesn't change anything in the output in my browser. What Execution Policy are you referring to (can't find anything within ISS)?

Comment: No Arkasha, Connect-VIserver is a cmdlet, available in PowerShell without specifying a path, once I've included all the VmWare snapins.

Comment: @MartijnBalink I've added a sort of two part answer below. Hopefully one of the approaches helps you.

Comment: Just to be sure: calling a plain powershell script from PHP (for example a Get-ChildItem -Recurse) in the exact same manner works like a charm, I get the expected output in my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the VMware PowerCLI installer has not added itself correctly to the user/machine environment variables, which are used to populate $Env:PSModulePath when PowerShell loads. The paths stored here determine where PowerShell can look for modules, and also aid cmdlet autoloading.

To resolve this in a way that persists across sessions, you can run the following:

```
$Current = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PSModulePath','Machine')
$Current += ';C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\Modules'
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PSModulePath',$Current,'Machine')
```

The gets the existing content of PSModulePath at a SYSTEM wide level, as you'd see here:

[image]

and appends the VMware PowerCLI module path to it, finally setting it by calling the SetEnvironmentVariable method.

Comment: I ran the PS1 script you suggested to alter the Env Variable. 
However, the Env variable is not altered. 
My PS1 script looks like this:`$Current = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PSModulePath','Machine')
$Current += ';C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\Modules'
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PSModulePath',$Current,'Machine')
write-host ($env:psmodulepath)` and it only outputs 
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\

Comment: I should have mentioned - you only need to run this once, with PowerShell elevated as Administrator. In your PowerCLI script, if it's still outputting just that last line, then try making the first line `$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ';C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\Modules'` - we use a line of this format for our PS1 scripts to add a custom module location that exists outside of the usual areas and it works well. Beyond this, I can only think it's something to do with the server OS / IIS / WMF versions... (always upgrade WMF if you can).

Comment: Running the path extension command from an Elevated powershell did not change anything in the web output. 
Adding the `$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ';C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\Modules'` into my script however solved everything. I can now run PowerCli commands from PHP. 
Thanks a lot!!!